# Disable and enable constraints temporarily so I can delete records

Tags: sql-server

I want this code to be put into the deletecommand of a sqldatabase in an aspx environment:

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"
    GO
    DELETE FROM Sales.Individual
    WHERE CustomerID ='20562'
    GO
    exec sp_msforeachtable @command1="print '?'", @command2="ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"
    GO
```

This way I can disable the constraints first, delete the specified record, the reestablish the constraints afterward. I can't get it to work somehow, does anyone have any idea on how I can go about this issue? Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't do that if I were you.  One solution would be to create a stored proc that deleted data from all related tables.  If you wanted to keep the related information for some reason, you could create a bit column on the Sales.Individual table called "IsDeleted" to report off of.

Comment: Pondering if this is the worst idea I've seen this year... Very likely.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to think this through. Suppose you disabled constraint and deleted the record. You **can't** put the constraint back in unless you also delete all the related records that were preventing you from deleting the original one in the first place.

Your options are to either delete all related records in order or make your relationships cascade on delete. Or better yet, do not delete records at all - see advice from dana. Though I personally prefer using `Deleted datetime null` over `IsDeleted bit null`.

Comment: Interesting, I had never though of time-stamping the deleted date.  Could be handy though if you wanted a background process that really deleted any "deleted" records older than 30 days or something.